# activity_display_message cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android

I'm following the android basic tutorial and have been stuck on this one most of the day.  I have highlighted the error line with '//'. I've tried all sorts of import lines .. previous searches seem to say it's an import defining type error.

```
package com.example.myapp3;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.`enter code here`
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `activity_display_message` an xml file in your `layout` folder?

Comment: What development environment are you using? Where are you seeing this error?

Comment: @Mark Campo check you resources file. may be it will help

Comment: Be sure in your *layout* folder you have a file called activity_display_message.xml and that there are no errors in that file. Try running Project->Clean after that if there is still an error. You can also check the *Problems* view in the console and see if there is anything else causing the error.

Comment: Eclipse  problems section when trying to run, following this guide  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: my activity_display_message is a .Java.. not .XML is that the issue i created it wrong?

Comment: gonna re go over tutorial part the creating the activity display was not clear and not matching my layout..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the guide you are following..it states

> Note: If you are using an IDE other than Eclipse, your project does
>   not contain the activity_display_message layout that's requested by
>   setContentView(). That's OK because you will update this method later
>   and won't be using that layout.

So just follow along.. your code will be updated.

On other note

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
```

here you are trying to set the view of your activity... and referencing the layout which does not exist.. if you will create a xml named `activity_display_message.xml` inside res->layout folder of your project.. error will resolve.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem and I couldn't find the answer anywhere on stackoverflow.  I tried cleaning, rebuilding etc. The help tip insisted that I should create the file but when I accepted the suggestion it said the file already existed.  What ultimately fixed it for me was just restarting the IDE.

Comment: This solution worked for me and is unfortunately a reality of Android Studio development. Trust yourself and if there is a weird bug, just restart/clear cache every once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

When you build an Android application, a file named **R.java** is created that contains identifiers for all of your resources. If the file **R.java** does not exist or does not contain an identifier for your layout, I can think of at least 4 possible reasons.

1. You do not have a file named **activity_display_message.xml** in your **layout** folder
2. You have a file with that name but it is not all lower case
3. You have an error in one or more of your resource files and R.java
   is not being created
4. Your development environment is not re-building **R.java** for some
   reason

In the case of number 4, try doing a "Clean"

Answer (score 0):

With which IDE are you working?

For Eclipse, you need to import R file generated for the project automatically if your project does not contain any error. The R file generated contains reference to your resources that you will be creating.

So make sure

1. You have a layout resource named activity_display_message in your layout folder which should have no errors.
2. Import the R file of the project in class so that the resources of projects will be available for you to use in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this line:
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
Had and error message underlining the text "activity_display_message", it still ran for me.

But I hated seeing the underline telling me there was something wrong.

After a bit of searching and trial and error I realized that the problem was that the auto generated file "activity_display_message.xml" was missing the proper xml first line.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Once I added that as the first line in the "activity_display_message.xml" file the error underline went away.

Answer (score 0):

If you see import android.R; in the imports , remove that as well. it resolved my compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Manifest.xml. Make sure that the activity is referenced there along with the package name where it is been defined.

Answer (score -1):

My problem was: after creating the activity_display_message in my xml file, I didn't save the changes. After hours of research, I saved the file and my problem is gone! Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

i turn off my Emulator and restart the idea,it work

Comment: Could you expand on how you 'turned off' your Emulator and what 'restart the idea' means? The more clarity you can offer here, the better for others who stumble upon this question via search.